# add new property in fosuserbundle and sonatauser

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata

i try to add new property i read this guide
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md
Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms

all are good only return to me this error
Neither property "name" nor method "getName()" nor method "isName()" exists in class "Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User"

probably Sonata not read the new property

how i can resolve? thx

Comment: in your new entity class you need to extend BaseUser. did you try that?

Comment: yes, the problem is this
i have install fosuserbundle,  after i have install sonatauserbundle
all work
after i decide to add, to entity User(Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php) the new property "name" i have add, but sonata want gettere and setter in "Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

Comment: Hi Mark, did you include the right namespace for the User Entity in your controller? (e.g. use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User` class extends your bundle's user class, but not `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`.